# Height of UITableViewCell based on cell Click

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

i am trying to change the height of the first  UITableViewCell of UITableView on click on the cell, i have been able to change the height on click but its not giving me the desired effect, it reduces the height from the top of the cell not the bottom, i want the height to be reduce from the bottom to a particular point towards the top. This is the code am using at present.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        return checkHeightBasedOnVisibility()
    }else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        return 300
    }else {
        return 200
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {



        if isVisible {
            isVisible = false
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
        else {
            isVisible = true
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}



// MARK: Private Methods
func checkHeightBasedOnVisibility() -> CGFloat {
    if isVisible {
        return 239
    }
    else {
        return 44
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using a custom UITableViewCell, and if so, what constraints have you set up?

Comment: did you upload your gif that show some error or issue ?

Comment: @MikeTaverne Thanks, the issue came from the constraints, and i have been able to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Make your `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` function look like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        isVisible = !isVisible
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this not what i want but it helped simplify my code

Answer (score 0):

The issue is from the constraints i set, i mistakingly constraint the bottom of table to a different view, instead of the view below it.